# SymPy: Solve several equations and display result in terms of specific variables

Tags: sympy

How can I tell [`sympy.solve`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/solvers.html?highlight=solve) in which variables to express the solution?

For example, I would like

```py
from sympy import *
a, b, c = symbols("a b c")
solve([
    Eq(a, b),
    Eq(b, c)
], a)
# => {a: b}
```

to return `{a: c}` rather than `{a: b}`, i.e. to express the solution in terms of `[c]`, but to eliminate `[b]` from the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unimplemented feature that has been described [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/2720#issuecomment-312437508)

If you use the two functions defined there you will be able to do this:

```py
a, b, c = symbols("a b c")
focus([
    Eq(a, b),
    Eq(b, c)
], a, b)
# => {a: c, b: c}
```

Comment: Thank you. The [issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/2720#issuecomment-312437508) is from 2014. Do you know why this or something similar like `eliminate` is not implemented in sympy core?

Comment: Features need advocates and there hasn't been much positive feedback. So this feature waits while other features are added. SO and SymPy issues end up being a collecting place for "recipes" that might be useful but haven't been added.