# Sympy system of differential equations

Tags: python, sympy, equation, differential-equations, symbolic-math

#### Problem

I'm making a symbolic solver for mechanical links [previous question for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76473155/sympy-solve-cant-eliminate-intermediate-symbols-from-systems-of-equations)

Right now I can get sympy.solve to solve big systems of linear equations, but I'm having an hard time making the solver resolve the partial differential equations. The solver *can* solve them, but it gets confused in when and what it should solve and doesn't output something useful.

Minimal Code:

```py
#Try to solve Y=Z X=dY(Z)^3/dZ
import sympy as lib_sympy

def bad_derivative_wrong( in_x : lib_sympy.Symbol, in_y : lib_sympy.Symbol, in_z : lib_sympy.Symbol ):
    l_equation = []
    l_equation.append( lib_sympy.Eq( in_y, in_z ) )
    l_equation.append( lib_sympy.Eq( in_x, lib_sympy.Derivative(in_y*in_y*in_y, in_z, evaluate = True) ) )
    solution = lib_sympy.solve( l_equation, (in_x,in_y,), exclude = () )
    return solution

def bad_derivative_unhelpful( in_x : lib_sympy.Symbol, in_y : lib_sympy.Symbol, in_z : lib_sympy.Symbol ):
    l_equation = []
    l_equation.append( lib_sympy.Eq( in_y, in_z ) )
    l_equation.append( lib_sympy.Eq( in_x, lib_sympy.Derivative(in_y*in_y*in_y, in_z, evaluate = False) ) )
    solution = lib_sympy.solve( l_equation, (in_x,in_y,), exclude = () )
    return solution

def good_derivative( in_x : lib_sympy.Symbol, in_y : lib_sympy.Symbol, in_z : lib_sympy.Symbol ):
    l_equation = []
    l_equation.append( lib_sympy.Eq( in_y, in_z ) )
    l_equation.append( lib_sympy.Eq( in_x, lib_sympy.Derivative(in_z*in_z*in_z, in_z, evaluate = True) ) )
    #what happens here is that Derivative has already solved the derivative, it's not a symbol
    solution = lib_sympy.solve( l_equation, (in_x,in_y,), exclude = () )
    #lib_sympy.dsolve
    return solution

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #n_x = lib_sympy.symbols('X', cls=lib_sympy.Function)
    n_x = lib_sympy.symbols('X')
    n_y = lib_sympy.Symbol('Y')
    n_z = lib_sympy.Symbol('Z')
    print("Wrong Derivative: ", bad_derivative_wrong( n_x, n_y, n_z ) )
    print("Unhelpful Derivative: ", bad_derivative_unhelpful( n_x, n_y, n_z ) )
    print("Good Derivative: ", good_derivative( n_x, n_y, n_z ) )
```

Output:

```
Wrong Derivative:  {Y: Z, X: 0}
Unhelpful Derivative:  {Y: Z, X: Derivative(Y**3, Z)}
Good Derivative:  {Y: Z, X: 3*Z**2}
```

#### Question:

I need a way to add partial derivative symbols to my equations in a way that the solver is happy to solve.

E.g. the speed is the derivative of the position over time.
E.g. the sensitivity of the position in respect to the angle is related to precision and force.

Comment: (1) Where are the partial derivatives? I only see a full derivative. (2) What are the inputs and outputs that you need to deal with? (3) you refer to "scypy" in your title. I assume that should be "sympy" and not an incorrectly-spelled "SciPy."

Comment: I made a minimal example where it fails. The system has has first and second order partial derivatives e.g. Ex(T1, T2, T3...TN-1) dTn for all coordinates (X,Y,Z,W,P,R) of all joints vs all joint angles (T1,T2, ...). I want to get the parametric forward transforation, inverse transformation and forward and inverse sensitivity.

Comment: My mistake, it's sympy and not scypi as you say. fixed the title.

Comment: If you specified variables to be functions, i.e. if you told sympy that `y` is a function of `z` and `x` is a function of `y` and `z`, you might be able to get what you want.

Comment: Can you give an example? I tried, even looking at examples, but I can't get solve to work on them.

Comment: I found another way to do it, which I've posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a while to find the answer, but I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61547194/12131013) that helped out. Essentially, there is a [(currently) open git issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/2720#issuecomment-312437508) that shares `seek` and `focus` functions. Solving your equations using the `focus` function will give you the `x` and `y` solutions as functions of `z` only. Since you aren't importing the entire sympy library (i.e. you aren't doing `from sympy import *`), which is how I also run sympy, we need to add import lines for `Eq` and `Tuple` to the functions, which I did below.

I also made a change that allows you to pass optionally pass `simplify` to `focus`. If you set `simplify=True`, it will simplify the results. This is what you want, otherwise, it will return `{y: z, x: Derivative(z**3, z)}`.

seek:

```py
def seek(eqs, do, sol=[], strict=True):
    from sympy.solvers.solvers import _invert as f
    from sympy.core.compatibility import ordered
    from sympy import Eq
    while do and eqs:
        for x in do:
            for e in eqs:
                if not isinstance(e, Eq):
                    continue
                i, d = f(e.lhs - e.rhs, x)
                if d != x:
                    continue
                break
            else:
                if strict:
                    assert None  # no eq could be solved for x
                continue
            sol.append((d, i))
            eqs.remove(e)
            break
        do.remove(x)
        if not strict:
            do.extend(i.free_symbols)
            do = list(ordered(do))
        for _ in range(len(eqs)):
            if not isinstance(eqs[_], Eq):
                continue
            # avoid dividing by zero
            ln, ld = eqs[_].lhs.as_numer_denom()
            rn, rd = eqs[_].rhs.as_numer_denom()
            eqs[_] = Eq(ln*rd, rn*ld).xreplace({x: i})
            if eqs[_] == False:
                raise ValueError('inconsistency detected')
    return sol
```

focus:

```py
def focus(eqs, *syms, **kwargs):
    """Given Equality instances in ``eqs``, solve for symbols in
    ``syms`` and resolve as many of the free symbols in the solutions
    as possible. When ``evaluate=True`` a dictionary with keys being
    ``syms`` is returned, otherwise a list of identified symbols
    leading to the desired symbols is given.

    Examples
    ========
    >>> focus((Eq(a, b), Eq(b + 2, c)), a)
    {a: c - 2}
    >>> focus((Eq(a, b), Eq(b + 2, c)), a, evaluate=False)
    [(b, c - 2), (a, b)]
    """
    from sympy.solvers.solvers import _invert as f
    from sympy.core.compatibility import ordered
    from sympy import Eq, Tuple
    evaluate = kwargs.get('evaluate', True)
    assert all(isinstance(i, Eq) for i in eqs)
    sol = []
    free = Tuple(*eqs).free_symbols
    do = set(syms) & free
    if not do:
        return sol
    eqs = list(eqs)
    seek(eqs, do, sol)
    assert not do
    for x, i in sol:
        do |= i.free_symbols
    do = list(ordered(do))  # make it canonical
    seek(eqs, do, sol, strict=False)
    if evaluate:
        while len(sol) > len(syms):
            x, s = sol.pop()
            for i in range(len(sol)):
                sol[i] = (sol[i][0], sol[i][1].xreplace({x: s}))
        for i in reversed(range(1, len(syms))):
            x, s = sol[i]
            for j in range(i):
                y, t = sol[j]
                sol[j] = y, f(y - t.xreplace({x: s}), y)[0]
    simplify = kwargs.get("simplify", False)
    if simplify:
        for i in range(len(sol)):
            sol[i] = (sol[i][0], sol[i][1].simplify())
    if evaluate:
        sol = dict(sol)
    else:
        sol = list(reversed(sol))
    return sol
```

Your example:

```py
import sympy as sp
x, y, z = sp.symbols("x y z")

l_equation = []
l_equation.append(sp.Eq(y, z))
l_equation.append(sp.Eq(x, sp.Derivative(y**3, z)))

solution = focus(l_equation, x, y, simplify=True)
print(solution)    # {y: z, x: 3*z**2}
```

As indicated by my explanation above, I give credit to those who originally developed this solution, I've only made some minor changes to suit the needs of this problem.

Comment: On point, this seems to solve more generically the issue of hinting at the solver what I want out of it. My sympy wasn't happy about one import, but was happy with: from sympy import ordered